# Cron job on specific time not working

Tags: cron, crontab, magento-2.1.8, schedule

I've written a custom module and this module has to run every day at 12:30 AM. I've written a cron job and in the schedule I've update as follows:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="daily_report" instance="mymodule\Mail\Cron\SendEmail" method="execute">
            <schedule>30 00 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Apparently this job is not running. I can't see any entries in cron_schedule schedule table as well.

When I change the schedule to every minute, this job is working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should remove one zero, so change it to <schedule>30 0 * * *</schedule>

Comment: i have same problem

Comment: <job name="vendor_module_reminder_email" instance="vendor\module\Cron\ReminderEmail" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 0 * * *</schedule>
        </job>

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the mistake was that I expected the cron job to get scheduled according to my server time. Apparently, the scheduler uses the **store** time and not the server time.

That is if your schedule is 30 0 * * *, it will run every day at 00:30 by the **store** time. You can check your current store time by placing an order and checking it's creation time in the admin panel.